# Replacing "tokens" in Python string with alternate values

Tags: python, python-2.7, interpolation

Imagine a script that receives a string:

`http://whatever.org/?title=@Title@&note=@Note@`

...and a list of tokens:

`['arg:Title=SampleTitle', 'arg:Note=SampleNote']`

What is the most Pythonic way to interpolate those tokens into the string, such that, using the above example, the following is produced:

`http://whatever.org/?title=SampleTitle&note=SampleNote`

I've considered:

1. Loop through the list and, for every string it contains, split out the token name, and do a regex replace on every instance of `@TOKEN_NAME` found; and
2. Use some sort of templating mechanism (similar to what one can do with Ruby's `ERB.template`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To use the Pythonic solution, adopt the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) specifications for [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> template = "http://whatever.org/?title={Title}&note={Note}"
>>> template.format(Title="SampleTitle", Note="SampleNote")
'http://whatever.org/?title=SampleTitle&note=SampleNote'
```

You can also unpack a dictionary of named arguments:

```
>>> template.format(**{"Title": "SampleTitle", "Note": "SampleNote"})
'http://whatever.org/?title=SampleTitle&note=SampleNote'
```

---

If you're stuck with your input format, you could easily switch to something more useful with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "http://whatever.org/?title=@Title@&note=@Note@"
>>> re.sub(r"@(\w+?)@", r"{\1}", s)
'http://whatever.org/?title={Title}&note={Note}'
```

*(see regex explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/sV3kP4/1))*

and process the tokens into a dictionary, too:

```
>>> tokens = ['arg:Title=SampleTitle', 'arg:Note=SampleNote']
>>> dict(s[4:].split("=") for s in tokens)
{'Note': 'SampleNote', 'Title': 'SampleTitle'}
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward; thank you. Could you explain what the `**` does in front of the dict in your second example?

Comment: I have run the above and the `re.sub` statement does not work

Comment: @MarkKortink any chance of a little more to go on than *"does not work"*?

Comment: When i set `s = "http://whatever.org/?title=@Title@&note=@Note@"` then run `re.sub(r"@(\w+?)@", r"{\1}", s)` i get `s` back unchanged. Is there a regex that can solve the initial problem without having to use `format()`? The reason, i am using jinja which uses `{{ }}` to bracket variables so given format uses `{ }` there is a chance of bugs.

Comment: @MarkKortink could not replicate. Are you thinking there would be an in-place transformation? Because strings are immutable.

Comment: Ah! That is my error, i assumed the `s` in `re.sub` would be changed. When i do `t = re.sub(r"@(\w+?)@", r"{\1}", s)` it works! Thanks